# Взаимодействие сайта с консольной программой

Tags: веб-программирование, asp.net, консоль

Есть консольная программа, которая обрабатывает определенные команды и выдает результаты. Команда отправляются с веб-странички и веб-страничка должная получить результат. Консольная программа и страничка запущены на одном компьютере. Как организовать механизм общения между страничкой и консолью в обоих направлениях

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть на SignalR - библиотекa от Microsoft, использует двунаправленную связь для обмена сообщениями между клиентом и сервером, позволяя напрямую вызывать методы друг друга.

Я использую [Named Pipe Wrapper](https://github.com/acdvorak/named-pipe-wrapper).